# Problem with LEFT JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables

```
countries:
id, name

results:
id, stat, type, country, value, date
```

`stat` can be any of 10 values and `type` one of 2. `Country` is the id of the country on the `countries` table.

Results for a specific date do not have all countries.

How can I create a `LEFT JOIN` so ALL countries are listed for EVERY `stat`-`type` combination, so if a country does not have results then 0 (or NULL) will be displayed.

I tried `SELECT * FROM dt_countries c LEFT JOIN results r ON c.id = r.country` as a test but it does not show the results I want.

thanks

Comment: Are the stats/types enumerated in another table or tables that we could leverage here?

Comment: Do you have a table with the result types and another table with the result values?

Comment: Do the stats/types exist in another table we could leverage here?

no, that is the only table

Comment: Do you have a table with the result types and another table with the result values
- No, those are the only 2 tables i can use. But the stats and type are predefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the table structure to support doing that (or, if you do, you don't have the table listed). What you need to do what you're after is three tables:

- countries
- results
- country results

(FYI, SQL tables are generally named in *singular* form, i.e. `Country`, `Result`, `CountryResult`, etc.)

What you've listed is just the equivalent of the `Country` and `CountryResult` table.

If you had the third table, you'd then do something like this:

```
select
    c.Name as Country,
    r.Name as Result,
    cr.Value as Value

from Country c

cross join Result r -- We WANT a cartesian product
left join CountryResult cr on cr.CountryId = c.CountryId and cr.ResultId = r.ResultId
```

Comment: So i should create on table with the stat-type list?

Comment: Am I missing something weird about MySQL? If you want a Cartesian product wouldn't you normally just do a CROSS JOIN and not have to do odd things like "1=1"?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, you would ordinarily use a `CROSS JOIN`. For some reason, I had it in my head that MySQL didn't support them, but that seems inaccurate. I've edited my answer; thanks!

Comment: @Jon: Yes, you should have a table that defines your list of possible stat types.

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM results r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dt_countries c 
    ON c.id = r.country
```

Comment: -1. This will not do what the OP asks for; this will only list results that don't have a valid `country`. It won't list results that don't exist.

Comment: it gives the same results in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select st.stat, st.type, r.date, c.name, r.value
from 
(select distinct stat, type from results) st
cross join dt_countries c
left outer join results r on 
   c.id = r.country and r.stat = st.stat and r.type = st.type
order by st.stat, st.type, r.date, c.name
```